# Remove control created at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote some code to create an additional `textbox` during runtime. I'm using the metro framework, but this shouldn't matter for my question.

When you click a button, a `textbox` is being created by a `private` `on_click` event:

```
private void BtnAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox Textbox2 = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox
    {
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(98, lblHandy.Location.Y - 30),
        Name = "Textbox2",
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23),
        TabIndex = 1
    };
    this.Controls.Add(Textbox2);
}
```

What I want to do now is to use the click event of another button, to remove the Textbox again. What I am not sure about is, if I have to remove just the controll or also the object itself. Furthermore I can neither access the Textbox2 Control nor the object from another place.

```
private void BtnRemoveTextbox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(Textbox2);
}
```

This does not work, since the other form does not know about `Textbox2`. What would be the best way to achieve my goal? Do I have to make anything public and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple `Textbox2`? Or only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find it first before you choose to remove it.

```
private void BtnRemoveTextbox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("Textbox2", true).FirstOrDefault() as MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox;
    if (tbx != null)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(tbx);
    }
}
```

Here, `Textbox2` is the ID of your textbox. Please make sure you're setting the ID of your textbox control before adding it.

Comment: Thank you both for your solutions. I went with the 2nd one :-)

Comment: Disposing of the controls is not optional. It's really important to dispose them after you removed them.

Answer (score 1):

Since the control was created in another form, the current form has no way of knowing it by its instance name.

To remove it, loop through all controls and look for **its `Name`**:

```
private void BtnRemoveTextbox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls) 
    {
        if (ctrl.Name == "Textbox2")
          this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills sure, why not?

Comment: Disposing of the controls is not optional. It's really important to dispose them after you removed them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find those controls using `Controls.Find` method and then remove and dispose them:

```
this.Controls.Find("Textbox2", false).Cast<Control>().ToList()
    .ForEach(c =>
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(c);
        c.Dispose();
    });
```

Comment: @KobyDouek Read the question carefully. `Name = "Textbox2"`.

Comment: Sorry mate, I was under the impression `Find` uses ID.

Comment: Disposing the control is really important to release handle and unmanaged resources.